# How could I send HTTP traffic from a computer only accesible via Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows, proxy, remote-desktop, http, tunneling

I'm developing a Web Service Client. The Web Service is an special Government service only accessible from an internal network.

Currently, I'm working connected to a remote computer in this internal network via Remote Desktop, and working in my program from there.

Actually, the only thing I need from that machine is their HTTP access to the Web service.
Is there a way to route HTTP petitions from my local machine to the remote one, so I could access locally to that Web Service? Both machines are Windows XP.

I've tried to find other opened ports in the remote machine network firewall but only remote desktop and ping seems to be working.

I hope I explained myself well enough. 
I've tried with HTTP proxy using FreeProxy, but with no luck. Maybe SSH tunneling or something like that? I'm more focused on developing...

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I would try SSH tunneling. But if your client is only accessible from RDP, you might have problems finding open ports to route your tunnels through.

Possibilities

1) have them open up the web service for your specific IP outside the network, with time limited client side SSL certificates for security ;-)

2) run an SSH server on the client inside the network. Route requests from the outside-client (at the RDP port) to the web service at 80/443

3) run an SSH client inside the network. Configure a tunnel, over an outgoing connection, where a remote port (at a SSH server outside the network which you control) is forwarded through the tunnel and again to the web service at 80/443

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I could solve the problem, but with a workaround, and not the best, i'm afraid.
Anyway, it works, and it fits our development needs.

A colleague manage to get Internet access from the client machine inside the network. Then, we created a VPN using an online service ([LeafNetwoks](http://www.leafnetworks.net/index.jsp)).

Now, from my local machine I can access the remote machine. We set up an HTTP Proxy there and now from my machine, I connect through this proxy and I get access to the Web Service.

Although complicated, this solutions works well, because I don't lose neither RDP or my local network.

However, I think that the usefulness of the question lies on the lack of Internet access, so I'm not going to mark my own answer as accepted. 
I think that, with the question given, grojo answer is better.